# Make swagger UI look as it does on their website

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Recently got swagger setup for use internally with my team. Functionality exists fine but the look and feel leaves more to be desired. I see there are a few questions on here about themes, but none really have answers other than it isn't really possible. What we have looks like classic swagger:

[image]

It's fine, but isn't that pretty. Then you look @ the swagger editor and it looks like:

[image]

Which imo is MUCH nicer and the forms are bootstrapy instead of boxy. Was wondering if it's possible to get ours to look like this. What files would need to be modified? styles.css?

Comment: I also found a new website from swagger that renders the spec which is suitable for both desktop and mobile - https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much details. But they are different UI component. Don't think just extracting `css` will do the job.

I believe you are referring to the **[Swagger UI](http://petstore.swagger.io)** vs the **[Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io)**

You can still load the spec in the editor and click on the `<` *(located in the middle bar)* to hide the editor text. That might partially do you job! :-)

[image: swagger]